# MSIEXEC - difference between /quiet and /passive

Tags: installation, windows-installer

So according to msdn

Quiet mode, no user interaction
      /quiet

Unattended mode - progress bar only
      /passive

so if I want to install MSI i usually use /qn /quiet and everything goes fine.

Just want to know what is /passive used for.

one thing That I see sometime that in msdn i just see /q is this the same as /qn

dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe /q /norestart

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

/qn no UI 
/quiet no user interaction 
**/passive** unattended mode (only progress bar)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Seems like a good answer to me

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking the dotNet Fx install you mention is a bootstrapper and isn't an msi or msiexec.  It does call a number of internal MSIs and mostly accepts switches and pass arguments in a manner consistent with MSI but it is not MSI.

/q{n | b | r | f | n+ | b+ | b-} was introduced in MSI 1.0 where /passive and others were introduced in 3.0 to make it easier for the common scenarios to be called.  For example /passive is equivalent to /qb!- REBOOTPROMPT=S

One thing to note about /QN vs /QB is that /QN can't perform a UAC elevation prompt because it has no UI.  It'll simply return a failure code.  /QB can because it has a UI.

Reference: [Standard Installer Command-Line Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

When MSI 3.0 came out I believe they were going to create a set of command line options that would apply to all installations, so passive would work on MSI-based setups as well as others. So passive is the equivalent of /qb (or something close to that). I prefer the older /q options because they are more explicit about what is shown and with more choices. Just use the commands that work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, `/passive` displays a progress bar and `/quiet` does not.  But it can vary depending on the contents of the MSI.

Comment: It would not vary. The progress bar in the /qb aka /passive mode doesn't depend on any authored UI.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: I'm fairly sure I've seen installers where `/quiet` shows UI, and I think I've seen cases where `/passive` doesn't (or not for the entire install).  Typically when the MSI is really just a wrapper for a home-grown installer, I think.  But it is possible that I am misremembering.

Comment: It's entirely possible to create an MSI that doesn't respect UILevel and pops a UI when it shouldn't.....  don't do that :)

Comment: Well, quite.  But I was looking at the question from the POV of someone writing a script or software package that calls `msiexec` against a third-party MSI, rather than the POV of someone writing an MSI.   Now that I look at the question again, I'm not sure what the OP intended.  :-)

Comment: Having done that more times then I can count, I'd say that person (lets call them an integrator)  has to learn the ways of MSI including all of the wrong ways so they can guard against the bad behaviors.